# Running mutiple test dll in VSTest task in CICD Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, ui-automation

We have a running CICD setup and recently I have integrated test automation in the pipeline by using VSTest@2 task by pointing to the dll file in the testAssemblyVer2 and all this is working as expected.

However, moving forward i need to execute multiple test projects (multiple dlls) in a single pipeline. To give an overview, test automation scripts are designed in a way that 1 component have multiple test automation projects to test it.

Can VSTest@2 task used in such a way that multiple individual dlls can executed in single pipeline?